# Apache rewrite rules for running a Symfony application in a sub-directory when rewrite rules already exist for legacy application

Tags: php, apache, symfony-2.3

Version Information: Apache v2.4.18 on Ubuntu, PHP version 7.1,Symfony v3.2

I've been trying to get this working for a couple of days now and keep hitting problems, I have an existing PHP application using a custom built framework with the following Apache VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dvlp.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site/com

    RewriteEngine   On

    # Do nothing for the Home page ('^/$'), specific directories, static files.
    RewriteRule ^/(?:$|shared|asset)|\.(?:php|ico|txt|xml) - [L]

    # Search engine friendly request URIs (most, but not all, without a query string).
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-]+/?)$                 /index.php?param1=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-\.]+/?)$  /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/(.+)$ /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [QSA]

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What I am trying to do is install a Symfony application to work within a sub-directory. I've created my Symfony application in */var/www/symfony-app* and created a symbolic link */var/www/my-site/com/my-symfony* which points to */var/www/symfony-app/web*.

I then tried the following on line 6 of my VirtualHost file:

```
RewriteRule ^/(?:$|my-symfony|shared|asset)|\.(?:php|ico|txt|xml) - [L]
```

Visiting *dvlp.mydomain.com/my-symfony* in the browser takes me to the directory listings for the */var/www/symfony-app/web* folder. I tried adding an index.php file to */var/www/symfony-app/web* which simply includes app_dev.php and it loaded the home page, but I I tried visiting *dvlp.mydomain.com/my-symfony/edit-personal-details* I get the 404 error page from my existing application.

I realised now that I need separate rewrite rules for this sub-directory, for Symfony this is usually written as the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

So I undid the change I made to line 6 of the VirtualHost file and added a new line as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^/my-symfony(.*)$ /my-symfony/index.php [L,QSA]
```

This results in a 404 error:

```
No route found for "GET /my-symfony/" (from "http://dvlp.mydomain.com/")
```

And if I try visiting *dvlp.mydomain.com/my-symfony/edit-personal-details* I get the same 404 error:

```
No route found for "GET /my-symfony/edit-personal-details" (from "http://dvlp.mydomain.com/")
```

The last thing I have tried is adding a prefix to my Symfony *routing.yml*:

```
my_symfony:
    resource: "@MySymfonyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /my-symfony
```

This then loads the pages correctly but with no images or stylesheets because they are trying to load from the DocumentRoot (e.g dvlp.mydomain.com/css instead of dvlp.mydomain.com/my-symfony/css).

I would appreciate any input as to where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working as intended by adding a "Location" tag containing specific RewriteRules and a RewriteBase for the Symbolic link. For information, final VirtualHost config below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dvlp.my-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site/com

    RewriteEngine On

    <Location /my-symfony>
        RewriteBase /my-symfony
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
    </Location>

    # Do nothing for the Home page ('^/$'), specific directories, static files.
    RewriteRule ^/(?:$|my-symfony|shared|asset)|\.(?:php|ico|txt|xml) - [L]

    # Search engine friendly request URIs (most, but not all, without a query string).
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-]+/?)$                 /index.php?param1=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-\.]+/?)$  /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/(.+)$ /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [QSA]

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```